Should variables of type `never` be assignable to typed object properties?
I have a function that in some case has a return type of never. My expectation was that if a function returned never it would not be allowed to be assigned to an object property that had a type, such as string[] below, specified. Is this expected behavior or a TypeScript bug? If it is expected behavior can someone please explain why this is possible?
interface LoaderData {
    disabledModules: string[]
}

function getDisabledModules(): never {
    throw new Error('Never returns');
}

const disabledModules = getDisabledModules();

const data: LoaderData = {
    disabledModules,
}

TS Playground with above example

It’s expected behavior, never is assignable to every type, see the linked q/a above.
